# Assessing accelerometer quality

Tags: measurement, accelerometer

How can I determine the quality of an accelerometer? Is there a standard measure, such as the SNR, or set of measures? What makes one accelerometer better than another; the accuracy of its sampling rate, and "noise" of its x,y,z samples?

Comment: Accelerometers have several dozens of parameters. The decision which one is better for your application is based on which parameters are significant for it. The same as with any other component.

Comment: My application is modeling touches on the screen of a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one measure of an accelerometer's quality. For a single channel, some of the characteristics which can affect the accelerometer's usefulness are

Bandwidth

Noise (typically expressed as g/(square root of bandwidth))

Thermal drift

Aging drift

Linearity

Resolution

Cross-axis coupling

Comment: (non) Linearity sometimes expressed as 'vibration rectification' for mil products.

Comment: Damping?  (I dunno.  Maybe for a MEMS accelerometer that's factored in to "bandwidth".)